# How to intuitively argue that $x < (n - 1) \ln (n x)$ for large $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

**Problem**.  Why does $e^x$ grow faster than $x^n$ for all real $n$?

**My strategy**.  The question seems to be asking for intuition, otherwise I'd expect words like "prove".  I've been taught the trick to express a polynomial $p(x)$ as $e^{\ln{p(x)}}$, which seems to be handy here.  This trick gives us a common base $e$ and, with a common base, I'm left with comparing the exponents.  Since it's about the rate of growth of these functions, it's really the derivative that I need to compare, so I get $e(x)$ and $n x^{n-1} = e^{(n-1)\ln{nx}}$ respectively.  Now the question is which exponent grows faster, $x$ or $(n-1)\ln({nx})$?

Intuitively, $x$ grows more than $(n - 1)$, so the constant $(n-1)$ doesn't matter and I may leave it out in the comparison: we just take $x$ greater than $(n - 1)$.  So it seems I'm left with comparing $x$ and $\ln(nx)$.  But I'm out of ideas now.  Can you help me to get rid of the $n$ inside of the natural log?  I would be able to build a strong argument if I'm comparing $x$ and $\ln(x)$, for example.

Comment: well, for very large x, you can immediately argue, that a linear term grows faster than any logarithm. for example: take the derivative on both sides: 
the derivative of x is 1, the derivative of (n-1)ln(nx) is (n-1)/x

for x > 2n-2, the right side grows only half as fast as x, so at some point x has to be larger than (n-1)ln(nx)

getting rid of n inside the logarithm: 
$ln(nx) = ln(n)+ln(x)$

Comment: Personally, I use l'Hopital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convince yourself that  ($\forall a,b>0$)

> $x$ grows faster than $a\ln(bx)$

i.e. that

> $\frac xa$ grows faster than $\ln(bx),$

i.e.

> $\frac u{ba}$ grows faster than $\ln u,$

draw the graph of $v=\ln u$ and the graph of arbitrary lines $v=cu$ for $c>0.$

Comment: Thank you, Anne. Your substitutions were very nice.  That's what I needed to continue.  Thank you so much.